# Change the button style if clicked in android

Tags: android, button, state

I have created a lot of buttons, in the java code, which represent some houses(for example). I want to create another button which is called "selection multiple". When i click on this button(selection multiple), all the others buttons(the houses) will change style or color when I click on them.
The problems is that I create the buttons ( house ) in the java code so i don't find how to change their style when I click on them /:

```
 Button macase = new Button (this);
 macase.setText("o"+Numcase);
 tr.addView(macase);
```

Comment: Don't worry about the English. Its a fix in progress :)

Comment: I'm writing an answer right now :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as far as I understand your problem is setting the Color of the button programatically.

You could for example do it like this:

```
 macase.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: oh ok ! I'll create an global variable wich represents if i've cliqued or no on the " selection multiple " . And the boutons i'll cliqued will check the value of the varibale and if the variable say it's an selection multiple i change the color but if the variable has no value the button had a normal comportement
Thansk you very much

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a reference to your button object, you can change it's image or background (for example) with these functions.

```
    macase.setImageResource(R.drawable.myicon);
    macase.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mycustomButton);
```

In the second case, mycustomButton is an XML file with the custom style you want to apply